# How to recursively include XML files in Python, keeping track of the original file and line?

Tags: python, xml, include

I'm preparing a Python framework that handles description of the system stored in XML files. The description is hierarchical, and should allow creating libraries with description of submodules. That requires support for including XML files. I have tried to use the [xml.etree.ElementInclude](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementInclude.py) module, but it seems that it does not handle correctly nested includes.

Therefore I have created my own solution, that replaces the include directive hidden in the XML comment:

```
<!-- include path/to/the/included_file -->
```

with the content of the included file. If the included file contains other include directives, they are handled recursively. The code is very simple:

```
import os.path
import re
R1 = r"<!--\s*include\s*(?P<fname>\S+)\s*-->"
P1 = re.compile(R1)

def handle_includes(file_path,base_dir="./"):
    """ Function handle_includes replaces the include directives:
    <!-- include path/to/the/included_file -->
    with the contents of the included file.
    If the included file also contains include directives, they
    are handled recursively.
    The base_dir argument specifies base directory for relative
    paths.
    """
    # Check if the file_path is relative or absolute
    if file_path[0] == '/':
        # absolute
        full_file_path = file_path
    else:
        # relative
        full_file_path = base_dir + '/' + file_path
    # Read the file contents
    contents = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()
    # Create the base directory for possible further includes
    next_base_dir = os.path.dirname(full_file_path)
    # Mark the start position
    start_pos = 0
    # List of the parts of the string
    chunks = []
    # Find the include directives
    incl_iter = P1.finditer(contents)
    for incl_instance in incl_iter:
        # Find the occurence of include
        include_span = incl_instance.span()
        # Put the unmodified part of the string to the list
        chunks.append(contents[start_pos:include_span[0]])
        # Read the included file and handle nested includes
        replacement = handle_includes(incl_instance.groups()[0],next_base_dir)
        chunks.append(replacement)
        # Adjust the start position
        start_pos = include_span[1]
    # Add the final text (if any)
    chunks.append(contents[start_pos:])
    # Now create and return the content with resolved includes
    res = ''.join(chunks)
    return res
```

The function is called by simple

```
final_xml=handle_includes('path/to/top.xml')
```

The above code works correctly, and the produced XML may be further handled by the [xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring). However, when the generated final XML becomes large, it is difficult to spot possible errors in deeply included XML files.
Is it possible to somehow attach the information about the original source files and line numbers to the produced XML?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to implement tracking the origin of the included lines.
The `handle_includes` function now returns not only the contents of the
file with inserted includes, but also the list of objects storing the origin 
of the blocks of lines. Each `LineLocation` object stores:

- The first line of the block in the resulting XML
- The last line of the block in the resulting XML
- Position of the first line of the block in the original file
- The path to the file from where the block was read

If error is detected during processing of a certain line in the final XML, that list
of objects allows easy finding the position of the corresponding line in the original sources consisting of mutiple files.

The implementation is only slightly more complicated:

```
import os.path
import re
R1 = r"<!--\s*include\s*(?P<fname>\S+)\s*-->"
P1 = re.compile(R1)
class LineLocation(object):
    """ Class LineLocation stores the origin of the
    block of source code lines.
    "start" is the location of the first line of the block
    "end" is the location of the last line of the block
    "offset" is the position of the first line of the blok in the original file
    "fpath" is the path to the file from where the lines were read.
    """
    def __init__(self, start, end, offset, fpath):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.offset = offset
        self.fpath = fpath
    def adjust(self, shift):
        self.start += shift
        self.end += shift
    def tostr(self):
   return str(self.start)+"-"+str(self.end)+"->"+str(self.offset)+":"+self.fpath

def handle_includes(file_path, base_dir="./"):
    """ Function handle_includes replaces the include directives:
    <!-- include path/to/the/included_file -->
    with the contents of the included file.
    If the included file also contains include directives, they
    are handled recursively.
    The base_dir argument specifies base directory for relative
    paths.
    """
    # Check if the file_path is relative or absolute
    if file_path[0] == '/':
        # absolute
        full_file_path = file_path
    else:
        # relative
        full_file_path = base_dir + '/' + file_path
    # Read the file contents
    contents = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()
    # Create the base directory for possible further includes
    next_base_dir = os.path.dirname(full_file_path)
    # Find the include directives
    # Mark the start position
    start_pos = 0
    # Current number of lines
    start_line = 0
    # Offset in lines from the beginning of the file
    offset_line = 0
    # List of the parts of the string
    chunks = []
    lines = []
    incl_iter = P1.finditer(contents)
    for incl_instance in incl_iter:
        # Find the occurence of include
        include_span = incl_instance.span()
        # Put the unmodified part of the string to the list
        part = contents[start_pos:include_span[0]]
        chunks.append(part)
        # Find the number of the end line
        n_of_lines = len(part.split('\n'))-1
        end_line = start_line + n_of_lines
        lines.append(LineLocation(start_line,end_line,offset_line,file_path))
        offset_line += n_of_lines
        start_line = end_line
        # Read the included file and handle nested includes
        replacement, rlines = handle_includes(incl_instance.groups()[0], next_base_dir)
        chunks.append(replacement)
        # Now adjust the line positions accorrding to the first line of the include
        for r in rlines:
            r.adjust(start_line)
        # Adjust the start line after the end of the include
        start_line = r.end
        # Append lines positions
        lines += rlines
        # Adjust the start position
        start_pos = include_span[1]
    # Add the final text (if any)
    part = contents[start_pos:]
    if len(part) > 0:
        chunks.append(part)
        # And add the final part line positions
        n_of_lines = len(part.split('\n'))-1
        end_line = start_line + n_of_lines
        lines.append(LineLocation(start_line, end_line, offset_line, file_path))
        offset_line += n_of_lines
    # Now create and return the content with resolved includes
    res = ''.join(chunks)
    return res, lines
```

Now the function should be called as

```
final_xml, lines = handle_includes('path/to/the/top.xml')
```